# Getting rid of YouTube subscribers

Tags: youtube

Recently, when switching between YouTube accounts I noticed that on one of my accounts I have 2 subscribers. Not sure where I earned them. Given that I am not a YT author, I don't really understand what having subscribers implies. How do I get to see the list and how do I get them unsubscribed (studio.youtube.com doesn't seem to have a way to do that).

Comment: It appears you can block them and there are quite a few guides how to do that online found with a simple search. There is also this Google forum thread discussing this: https://support.google.com/youtube/thread/51165403/how-to-remove-subscribers?hl=en

Comment: You are fantastic and so helpful